# Why AV Export session exports black video if AVAsset contains time-lapse video? How To resolve the issue?

Tags: swift, avcomposition, timelapse

I have created a function which generates avcompostion according to AVAsset duration and content.

If the video is slow-mo or regular it works completely fine but when videoType is time-lapse it shows black screen after exporting.

If I played AVAsset on avplayer it shows perfect time-lapse. Problem only occurs while exporting.